# Вопрос по спойлеру на css

Tags: css

Здравствуйте!
Есть код спойлера на чистом css

```
.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}
.main-item:focus ~ .sub-menu,
.main-item:active ~ .sub-menu,
.sub-menu:hover
{
    display: block;
}

<a class="main-item" href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="1" >Читайте больше...</a>
<div class="sub-menu">
Текст
</div>
```

который имеет огромный недостаток - закрывается не по клику на ссылку, а по клику в любую область вне текста. Мне известно, что есть масса способов реализации того же самого на яве. Но все-таки, уж очень привлекает простота данной реализации, есть ли возможность доработать данный код, чтобы зарывало по клику на ссылку и не закрывало по клику вне текста? Буду весьма благодарен за помощь.

Comment: java!=javascript если браузер поддерживает :checked то можно через чекбокс реализовать.

Comment: да, вы правы, я имел ввиду яваскрипт, конечно, ява это совсем другое :)

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/82V8t/

HTML:

```
// label может содержать в себе один input, при клик на label в этом случае равен клику на label
<label class="main-item">Читайте больше...
    <input class="readmore" type="checkbox" />
    <div class="sub-menu">Текст</div>
</label>
```

CSS:

```
.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}
/* взять в под-элементах .main-item следующий элемент с классом sub-menu после элемента input 
   с классом readmore, на котором стоит галочка */
.main-item input.readmore:checked + .sub-menu {
/*показать его*/
    display: block;
}
.readmore {
/*скрыть чекбоксы*/
    display: none;
}
```

стили, чтобы было похоже на `<a>` сделайте сами.

[вот еще вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/82V8t/1/) - чтобы только по клику на label закрывалось, но тогда придется приделывать к каждому input уникальный id.

[ещё вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/82V8t/2/) со своими минусами

Comment: Спасибо! Будьте добры, поясните, что к чему. Честно говоря, немного надоедает использовать готовые решения, не понимая, как работает:)

ps что-то на 9-м эксплорере не работает

Comment: у меня нет 9го экслорера, но по описанию должно работать как-раз с 9го

Comment: А еще можно переложить ответственность за отображение на общий для содержимого и выключателя родительский элемент, вот так: http://jsfiddle.net/zsaF5/1/.

Теперь спойлер закроется только при клике вне него, но по тексту внутри него можно тыкать сколько угодно. Только если внутри не будет другого элемента, который может получать фокус.

Comment: @Bars как это решает проблему описанную Aviko ?

Comment: @eicto Если ты раскроешь спойлер, а потом захочешь, к примеру, что-то выделить внутри блока, который только что был скрыт, спойлер не свернется. А свернется он только при клике вне контейнера спойлера.

Твои варианты, конечно, лучше, но некоторые менее неприхотливы к браузерам, некоторые сложнее в разметке. Мой вариант подойдет только для случаев, при которых спойлер скрывает [спойлер][1]


  [1]: http://lurkmore.to/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80

Comment: дык задача ТС сводилась к тому чтобы не закрываться при клике вне спойлера, у него там :hover был чтобы не закрываться при клике на спойлере.